# How to license ActiveX control in Microsoft Access/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, activex

For the past few months, I have been developing a VBA software that uses the ActiveX Treeview control. I had no issues with using the control until today when suddenly I get the following error:

> You don't have the license required to use this ActiveX control.
>
> > You tried to open a form containing an OLE object or an ActiveX control or you tried to create an ActiveX control. To obtain the appropriate license, contact the company that provides the licensed OLE object or ActiveX control.

How does one go about getting and using the license for these controls?

Comment: What's the bitness of your VBA host application? ActiveX controls simply won't work on 64-bit hosts. That alone should be a gigantic no-no for going forward with this anticated tech.

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's a 32-bit host. It was working fine yesterday and before. But just today I get this issue.

Comment: Still, MS Common Controls were made for use in VB6, which uses a completely different library than VBA's MSForms UI library (although MS-Access has its own "forms" and designer *on top of that*) - and even if you got that TreeView to work on 32-bit Access VBA, you'll be royally F'd when you migrate/upgrate to a 64-bit host. Consider making your UI with .net / VSTO instead; with WPF/XAML your UI creativity will be practically without limits, and you'll be working with current tech instead of stuff from 25 years ago.

Comment: I would prefer to continue using the ActiveX TreeViews since I have already written a good amount of code with them but I may just have to look into those dev tools you mentioned as an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug caused by an update of the *CommonControl* control.

It will be fixed as noted [here](https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fhelp%2F4011093%2Faugust-22-2017-update-for-office-2016-kb4011093&data=02%7C01%7CMVP-NDA-Access%40windows.microsoft.com%7C1fea80ada4554999002808d4eb0a7b08%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636391877646397725&sdata=UhaSI3tsKWMIPkNLRcCJfNCEZ5C2GC%2Fi1t4x6suzW70%3D&reserved=0) with an upcoming update.

Comment: Interesting (upvoted). So, would you recommend using *common controls* in any new development work?

Comment: I checked my Installed Updates window to see if I had the KB4011051 update (the one that causes this issue) installed and I could not find it. I downloaded the patch, KB4011093, anyways but to no avail. This must mean my issue is stemming from elsewhere, no?

Comment: I don't think so. It has been reported numerous times with the symptoms you mention. Also note, that there are both an MSI install and an Office 365 install. Update intervals differ between these.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: This seems to be an bug with a relatively quick fix, so I wouldn't judge from this issue. It's rather a question about distribution and, as you mention, the lack of 64-bit support.

Comment: I did a force update of MA and the bug about obtaining the license is indeed gone. However, now a different issue arises. When I try to use my ActiveX TreeView control in my code, I get a compiler error. "Object library feature not supported".

Comment: Nevermind I resolved this checking my references and removing one that I was not using. Not sure why that was causing issues in the first place but whatever works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have a nice weekend.